# Update value in a file and ignore if there is no input for a variable in python

Tags: python, jenkins

I am getting few variables from jenkins to python. This python gets the file as a input and check for specific content and replaces the value with the user input provided through jenkins.

My  requirement is that when no inputs was provided through jenkins, value in file should be same as before. Currently for me, its getting replaced as `None`. Please suggest on this.

Thanks in advance!

My Python code is as below:

```
import fileinput
import os

username = os.getenv("username")
Password = os.getenv("Password")
hostname = os.getenv("hostname")

for line in fileinput.input('C:\\Jenkinsfile_test', inplace=True):
    if line.startswith('def username'):
        print "def username=",username
    elif line.startswith('def Password'):
        print "def Password=",Password
    elif line.startswith('def hostname'):
        print "def hostname=",hostname
    else:
        print line.strip()
```

My Jenkinsfile_test is as below,

```
def skipRemainingStages = false

def username=un
def Password=pwd
def hostname=host

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                .......
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added a check that a value has been provided by the environment to each condition.

```
for line in fileinput.input('C:\\Jenkinsfile_test', inplace=True):
    if line.startswith('def username') and username is not None:
        print "def username=",username
    elif line.startswith('def Password') and Password is not None:
        print "def Password=",Password
    elif line.startswith('def hostname') and hostname is not None:
        print "def hostname=",hostname
    else:
        print line.strip()
```